# Laravel 5.2 Validation - Using before and after only if the other date was sent in

Tags: php, laravel, validation

So I have the following validation:

```
'birth_date'             => 'date_format:Y-m-d|before:deceased_date',
'deceased_date'          => 'date_format:Y-m-d|after:birth_date',
```

The problem is that neither of these are required fields. Someone can enter a deceased date without a birth_date and vice versa. Currently, if you send in a deceased date with no birth date it fails the `after` validation. Is there a way to check the `before` / `after` checks ONLY if the other date was sent in?

To be clear, here would be the validation scenarios:

- both sent in: check before and after validations
- only one sent in: ignore before and after validations

Its okay to send in only one. I just want to be sure that if they send in both that it checks that the person didn't die before they were born and vice versa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `required_with` and `bail` both to solve your problem as:

```
'birth_date'     => 'bail|required_with:deceased_date|date_format:Y-m-d|before:deceased_date',
'deceased_date'  => 'bail|required_with:birth_date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:birth_date',
```

**Update**

You can try `sometimes` for your problem as:

```
$validation = Validator::make($formData, [
    ...
]
$validation->sometimes('birth_date', 'before:deceased_date', function($input){
    return ($input->birth_date && $input->deceased_date);
});
```

Comment: see my comment on saumya answer. Here are the test scenarios:
both sent in: check before / after validations
only one sent in: ignore before / after validations

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's validation rule - [`required_with`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-required-with), like this:

```
'birth_date'     => 'required_with:deceased_date|date_format:Y-m-d|before:deceased_date',
'deceased_date'  => 'required_with:birth_date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:birth_date',
```

> **required_with:foo,bar,...**
>
> The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

Hope this helps!

Comment: close, but not quite. Im not looking to require birth_date or deceased_date based on if another one is sent in. I am completely okay with them sending in only one of those fields no matter what. What I am looking for is a way to ONLY check before or after validations IF they both exist. So if someone sends in deceased_date but not birth_date I don't want it to fail on the after validation but if they send in both i want it to check the before and after.